# C++ :String reversal not working?

Tags: c++, string, character-arrays

I am having trouble understanding the output I am getting for this piece of code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    char ch[2][14];
    char re[2][14];

    cout << "\nEnter 1st string \n";
    cin.getline(ch[0], 14);

    cout << "\nEnter the 2nd string\n";
    cin.getline(ch[1], 14);

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int len = strlen(ch[i]);
        for(j = 0, k = len - 1; j < len; j++, k--) {
            re[i][j]=ch[i][k];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nReversed strings are \n";
    cout << re[0];
    cout << endl << re[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

for example

```
 /* 
    Input : 
    hello
    world

    Output :
    olleh<some garbage value>dlrow
    dlrow
  */
```

Sorry if it very basic, but I can't understand the reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).  You should also avoid reversing strings.  In many cases byte wise reversal of strings (which is what `std::reverse` will accomplish, and what you're attempting here) will produce wildly unexpected and incorrect results, for example, when working with UTF-8 data.

Comment: you forgot to terminate the reversed strings

Comment: And try to avoid including stdio.h in your c++ code...

Comment: ...by using cstdio if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot about the terminating zero for strings in array `re` Simply define the array the following way

```
char ch[2][14] , re[2][14] = {};
                           ^^^^
```

Also take into account that you should remove header `<stdio.h>` because it is not used and instead of it include header `<cstring>`.

This task can be done with using standard algorithm `std::reverse_copy`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 2;
    const size_t M = 14;

    char ch[N][M] = {};
    char re[N][M] = {};

    std::cout << "\nEnter 1st string: ";
    std::cin.getline( ch[0], M );

    std::cout << "\nEnter the 2nd string: ";
    std::cin.getline( ch[1], M );

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::reverse_copy( ch[i], ch[i] + std::strlen( ch[i] ) , re[i] );
    }

    for ( const auto &s : re ) std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `re[0]` and `re[1]` are null-terminated

For example during initialization you could do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    re[0][i] = '\0';
    re[1][i] = '\0';
}
```

But aside from that I suggest to used `std::string` and `std::reverse` and the like.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    int len = strlen(ch[i]);
    for (j = 0, k = len - 1; j < len; j++, k--)
    {
        re[i][j] = ch[i][k];
    }
    re[i][len] = '\0';
}
```

you have to terminate your reversed strings.

also you should `#include <string.h>` for the `strlen()` function.